# Ember data, how to get dispose of models in isError state

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

If I try and persist a model to a backend API and it fails, the model record is still in the store.

E.g.

```
todo.one 'becameError', (result)  ->
  #result.get('isError') == true
```

If I do a call to App.Todo.all(), the todo that failed is in the store and will appear in the app unless I filter out objects that have an isError state.

Is there a way I can dispose of the object when it is in this state?

I cannot call deleteRecord because there is an assertion stopping it being called for models that are an in an isError state.

Answer (score 1):

Why not call `rollback` on the record that failed to be saved, updated or deleted? So you would at least have a clean record to retry your operation.

For example:

```
todo.one 'becameError', (result)  ->
  result.get('transaction').rollback();
```

Hope it helps.